# AngularJS Hello World does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting started with AngularJS and surprisingly this super simple piece of code is not working. This page is served by expressJS with the hogan render engine.

The console doesn't say anything and my file paths are all correct and double checked. Still this simple data-binding does not work. Please help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <script src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app>
        <input type="text" ng-model="unm">
        <h2>Hello {{unm}}</h2>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's more to the story you're not mentioning. Here is your code on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/soneleno/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Actually I did mention that the page is served by the Hogan render engine using ExpressJS. The problem was Hogan as mentioned in my reply below.

Comment: Then you shared the wrong output with us. Should have typed `<h2>Hello </h2>` =p

Comment: I had no idea Hogan was stripping off all Angular template code as well.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. As I mentioned, I'm using the Hogan render engine in Express which has the same template brackets {{ }} as AngularJS. Hence when the page is rendered, Hogan strips all {{ }} thereby virtually removing the {{unm}}.

I've solved this problem by adding this line to my ExpressJS app :

```
app.locals.delimiters = '{{{ }}}';
```

Now, Hogan variables can be put inside {{{somevariable}}} while Angular works with its usual {{unm}}. They no longer conflict now.